# What does a DNS query look like?

Tags: http, go, dns, server

I'd like to make a simple DNS server using Go. I know how DNS works but I'm not 100% sure as to how a DNS query actually looks.

For example, a HTTP GET request looks like this:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

So my question is, does a DNS query look something like this:

```
QUERY google.com A
```

Or do DNS servers interpret the binary representation the domain name being queried?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the earlier replies. Go read RFC 1035 and start coding. Yes, there's an enormous amount of complexity that's been added after that, but if all you want to do is to respond to a few basic queries you don't need any of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out the [`miekg/dns`](https://github.com/miekg/dns) project.
It builds [Msg](https://github.com/miekg/dns/blob/877e47b4c3dbf1d632c9abe2a0960123f65bf222/msg.go#L77) compose of a [`MsgHdr`](https://github.com/miekg/dns/blob/877e47b4c3dbf1d632c9abe2a0960123f65bf222/msg.go#L59-L73) which includes the [QUERY code](http://OpcodeToString) (amongst [other OpCodes](http://OpcodeToString)).

That follows the Message Header you can see in "[Chapter 15 DNS Messages](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch15/)".